# Box Shadow - Thinner on outside

Tags: html, css

Using only CSS, how to give a div a shadow which is thicker in the middle and gets thinner as it goes out? `box-shadow` doesn't seem to provide a way.

There is an example here, http://www.ifirma.pl/bonusy. The header has the shadow that I want:

[image]

However this one is done with a background image. Is it possible purely in CSS?

Comment: I don't see how your example relates to your question.

Comment: Sorry Mr Lister, it's difficult to see there. If you go to this page you'll see it much better. Plus my explanation wasn't great: http://www.ifirma.pl/bonusy.

The header has a shadow which starts thick in the middle, and thins out as it gets further out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible!

See, https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

> Using a negative spread radius, you can get squeeze in a box shadow and only push it off one edge of a box.

```
.one-edge-shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
          box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```

Also try, "Effect 6" from the examples in the provided link above.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, and more! Stunning effects using just box shadow! Thanks a lot. I must keep an eye on that CSS Tricks site, I've seen it a few times and it's got some excellent guides.